# Remove elements from an array by matching a property of elements in another array

Tags: arrays, swift

I have two arrays:

```
var sessionsToDisplay : [SessionData]
var sessionsToDisplayTemp : [SessionData]
```

The `SessionData` class has a `startTime` Property. So, if the first `sessionToDisplay` array contains these items:

```
SessionData(startTime: "08:00", ...),
SessionData(startTime: "10:30", ...),
SessionData(startTime: "13:30", ...),
SessionData(startTime: "16:00", ...),
```

and the `sessionsToDisplayTemp` contains these:

```
SessionData(startTime: "06:30", ...),
SessionData(startTime: "16:00", ...),
SessionData(startTime: "12:30", ...),
SessionData(startTime: "15:30", ...),
SessionData(startTime: "08:00", ...),
```

I have to remove elements from `sessionsToDisplayTemp`, whose `startTime` is already there in the first array. So the result should be an array that has these elements:

```
SessionData(startTime: "06:30", ...),
SessionData(startTime: "12:30", ...),
SessionData(startTime: "15:30", ...),
SessionData(startTime: "08:00", ...),
```

Comment: Unrelated but as `startTime` seems to have always a value, why is it optional?

Comment: For String array, It's possible using "array1 = array1.filter { array2.contains($0) }" But don't know with Custom Array. Please suggest..

Comment: I mean to **declare** `startTime` as non-optional to get rid of all the question and exclamation marks.

Comment: Never mind. It's not that important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `filter` to check that an object isn't in the other array

```
let out = sessionsToDisplayTemp.filter {data in
    !sessionsToDisplay.contains {$0.startTime == data.startTime}
}
```

or if you want to remove them directly

```
sessionsToDisplayTemp.removeAll { data in
    sessionsToDisplay.contains {data.startTime == $0.startTime}
}
```